# PC wakes from suspend even when /proc/acpi/wakeup is disabled

Tags: 20.04, suspend, lenovo, thinkpad, touchscreen

**PC Model: Thinkpad X1 Tablet Gen 2**

**OS: Linux Ubuntu 20.04 LTS**

I have a Thinkpad X1 Tablet, and the keyboard is quite flexible which always wakes the PC up from sleep (the keyboard and the screen making contact and in turn turning on the PC).

This causes then my PC to get hot, and drain battery which I do not want.

I want it only to wake using the Power Button which is why I have disabled everything in `/proc/acpi/wakeup` other than `PWRB` which is the Power button.

I cannot understand what causes the wakeup, when I suspend my PC, nothing happens when I press the keyboard, move the mouse or anything. But when I put it in my bag, it may wake up on the way.

The keyboard is detachable and it has a touch screen, I do not know if this can be the cause of anything.